# Onload: If UserID in database exists, set javascript variable to true

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database

I have a database where a Facebook User ID, Facebook User Name and mail address is written. When the document loads I want to check if a given ID (stored in a javascript value) already exists in the database. So what I would have to do is check with PHP if my Javascript variable (value) exists in the database. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way would be to fire a XHR (AJAX) request to your server (PHP script) that contains the ID, and then check for the existence of that ID on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using ajax.

using jQuery for example:

```
$.post("check.php",{id: your_var},function(data){
  alert(data);
});
```

check.php holds your php code that checks the db.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need AJAX.
For example:

```
<script>

//user id
var uid = '100';

//AJAX create
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

//GET request create and send
xmlhttp.open("GET","checkuser.php?uid="+uid,false);
xmlhttp.send();

//Good. in "xmlhttp.responseText" will store true or false (user exist or not)
alert(xmlhttp.responseText); //check answer from PHP

</script>
```

Ok. Now PHP script.

//this is checkuser.php

```
<?php 
  $uid = int()$_GET['uid'];
  echo (bool)functionForCheckIdInDB($uid);
?>
```

p.s. of course with jQuery it easier.